# Determined to Use Gmail as default Windows 10 email protocol

Tags: windows, powershell, gmail, protocols, email-attachments

I am stubborn. It would be much easier to set up outlook, thunderbird, etc. Please provide feedback on my suggested solution to use gmail instead.

I use a screenshot program called "Greenshot". I would like to make use of the context menu function "send with email" (for a recently captured screenshot). However when I do this, I cannot set up a web based email client like gmail in windows 10.

Would it be possible to create a short script in Powershell like:
https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-send-mailmessage-gmail/

Except this would also allow customization of the "To:" "body" and other fields.

Basically I'm looking for a minimal way to interact with gmail instead of using a different standalone client.

Thanks,

Comment: The [registry](https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) is the right place for your needs…

Comment: The context menu shortcut is already built into the application UI, the problem is I cannot select a web based email client for window default email protocol

Comment: The email option is based on programs that register themselves as email client e.g. Outlook, Thunderbird etc. The send to email option will not work, with minimal effort. I would suggest that you instead save it to a directory where you can have a running scripts (every 2-5 minutes ?) that looks for new image files and emails them for you.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I would rather be able to send it immediately to a recipient of my choosing, rather than scanning every few minutes and emailing to myself

Comment: [Sending email from desktop programs, is more complicated.  You need to install a "simple MAPI" program to intercept those requests and launch Gmail in your browser](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/7dHrFlSd8rk). There are some links to "simple MAPI" programs in the _bkennely_'s  answer.

Comment: Thank you JosefZ!

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or does the link *you provided* already contain a script that lets you modify the body, To:, etc..?

*From the link you pasted, specifically for gmail:*

```
##############################################################################
$From = "YourEmail@gmail.com"
$To = "AnotherEmail@YourDomain.com"
$Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"
$Attachment = "C:\temp\Some random file.txt"
$Subject = "Email Subject"
$Body = "Insert body text here"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential (Get-Credential) -Attachments $Attachment
##############################################################################
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. the problem is the power shell script I'll be pre-formatted. I would like to be able to change the To: email field , body field, etc. Ess etially I'm looking for a mini script that will be a go-between to reach Gmail and send a messagw

Comment: ..but...but....that's _exactly_ what this is!!!  If you want to change the above body, then just change it to a pre-canned body.... literally all you have to do is change one variable in the code above.

Comment: I should have clarified in the original posting. I know it is easy to change one variable, but the whole point of this is absolute efficiency. And changing a variable in the script is more hassle than just saving the screenshot on my desktop and opening up chrome. 

I would like to be able to right click after taking a screenshot (greenshot program) and using the context menu to send as email (through gmail). Since gmail itself cant be used with windows protocol, I'm looking to create a mini-applet that allows me to add vital information to the email, and then send it through gmail.

Comment: So you would like to send an email of the last screenshot you took via gmail, directly from greenshot?

Comment: Yes this is what I would like